# why is this matrix rank deficient?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I assumed if column vectors (and/or row vectors) are independent, then a matrix is full rank; octave tells me this matrix has rank 2. Why?

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    2 & 3 & 4 \\
    3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Comment: The columns aren’t independent, the first and third columns average to the second column.

Comment: Thanks. I feel like such a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Naming your columns $x_1,x_2,x_3$. Compute $$x_1 - 2x_2 + x_3$$

Answer (score 0):

since your matrix is symmetric you can make your matrix congruent to a diagonal matrix.

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
3 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$